# Log4Net How to Log plain text without time

Tags: c#, vb.net, logging, log4net

I'm writing logs to a text file using Log4Net.dll v1.2.10. 
Here is how I'm logging the information:

```
Private loger As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger("MyAppName")

loger.Debug("some message")
```

Here is what I see in log text file:

```
2018-10-25 13:46:15,970 [6] DEBUG - [MyAppName] some message
```

My question: Is it possible to only log "some message" text in file without timestamp and other extra information?

Any kind of solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Look for `appender`, `layout`, `conversionPattern` in your config file & refer to this link for [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is very easy. Configure your file appender to use this layout pattern:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
</layout>
```